# (GMS2) Spawner object doesn't spawn items

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

In GMS2 I have a spawner item with the following code:

- In the create event:

  ```
  timer = 0;
  ```
- In the step event:

  ```
  if(distance_to_object(obj_coffe_bean) > 2) 
      if(timer == 200) {
          instance_create_layer(x, y, obj_coffe_bean, obj_coffe_bean);
          timer = 0;
      }
  else timer++;
  ```

This works perfectly fine, coffee beans are spawned when it doesn't detect any coffee bean nearby.

The problem is that the same code doesn't work when I duplicate this object and create a spawner for another item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I needed to use instance_create_depth instead of instance_create_layer.

Comment: This solution works, but you won't be able to set it to a specific layer that way. (Like Yellow said, you've defined the `obj_coffe_bean` twice, where one of them should have been the name of the layer it appears on)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem here would be that you are using the object index as the layer index in instance_create_layer - your code only works by chance (of there being a layer with a matching ID).